# Why does different values of 'x' in waitKey('x') gives different outputs in opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

At first I tried `if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q')`  then my output video is not a continuous stream, then I tried `if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')`, it worked fine. I would like to know what might be the reason for this different behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc - https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey

```
cv.WaitKey(delay=0)
```

`WaitKey` will take one parameter : **delay** – Delay in milliseconds. 0 is the special value that means “forever”.

> The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely (when
>   \texttt{delay}\leq 0 ) or for delay milliseconds, when it is positive.
>   Since the OS has a minimum time between switching threads, the
>   function will not wait exactly delay ms, it will wait at least delay
>   ms, depending on what else is running on your computer at that time.
>   It returns the code of the pressed key or -1 if no key was pressed
>   before the specified time had elapsed.